# JSF - Selecionar Item de um Conjunto

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

Quero fazer um xhtml que retorne uma lista de usuários e do lado apareça um botão para selecionar determinado usuário. Algo assim:

+----------------------------+
| ID | Usuário | (Botão) |
+----------------------------+

Minha duvida é: Como faço um laço de repetição no xhtml para construir a pagina com todos os objs q estão dentro do conjunto e qual é a melhor maneira para fazer o botão referencia o respectivo objeto de sua linha.

Se alguém puder me ajuda. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jhow,

Como o Tiago falou acima, você pode utilizar o dataTable do PrimeFaces ou pode usar também o dataTable do JSF. 
Segue um exemplo abaixo.

Vamos ter na sua classe "@ManagedBean("usuario")" uma lista do objeto que você quer inserir na tabela.

```
    private List<Usuario> usuario = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

   <h:dataTable value="#{usuario.usuario}" var="u">

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Order No</f:facet>
                    #{u.id}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Product Name</f:facet>
                    #{u.nome}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
                    #{u.sexo}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Quantity</f:facet>
                    <h:commandButton value="submit" type="submit" action="#{usuario.fazAlgumaCoisa(u)}" />
                </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
```

Segue um link de referência.
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/

Answer (score 1):

Datatable é o que a maioria usa
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

Tente

```
<p:panelGrid columns="3"> .... </p:panelGrid>
```

O p: é do primefaces mas funciona tambem com JFS puro.

Comment: Me ative ao desenho. 
Relendo a pergunta acredito o mais adequado a necessidade ser mesmo um dataTable como mencionado por outros colegas.